# Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat while working on Yarn Install

Tags: node.js, angular, yarnpkg

From today onward, I getting the following error while using the command `yarn install`

> error An unexpected error occurred: "ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Yarn\Cache\v2
>   \npm-@clr\icons-1.1.5-334ff790cd2f5ec67a034282c5709aac1a3de0b7
>   \shapes\CredDB.CEF'".
>   info If you think this is a bug, 
>   please open a bug report with the information provided in "C:\abcd-project\12-Mar-2020-M62\vxrail-nvt\yarn-error.log".
>   info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install 
>   for documentation about this command.

It is an angular NodeJs type project where I am using yarn as package manager (version 1.10.1).

Answer (score 0):

This issue is resolved after making some trials. This issue occurs only in Dell computers only because of Dell Encryption. I assume that the Dell Encryption got corrupted. When I installed Dell Encryption driver, the problem does not occur and hence it is resolved. I have to download the Dell Encryption driver from the following link.

https://dl.dell.com/FOLDER06110901M/1/Dell-Encryption-10.6.0.2.zip.
The parent link of the above link is given below.

https://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/product-support/product/dell-data-protection-encryption/drivers

From the above link, you have select **Dell Encryption**, after installation, you have to restart the system.